# Add numeric column to pandas dataframe based on other textual column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['137', 'earn'], ['158', 'earn'],['144', 'ship'],['111', 'trade'],['132', 'trade']], columns=['value', 'topic'] )
print(df)
    value  topic
0   137   earn
1   158   earn
2   144   ship
3   111  trade
4   132  trade
```

And I want an additional numeric column like this:

```py
    value  topic  topic_id
0   137   earn    0
1   158   earn    0
2   144   ship    1
3   111  trade    2
4   132  trade    2
```

So basically I want to generate a column which encodes a string column to a numeric value. I implemented this solution:

```py
topics_dict = {}
topics = np.unique(df['topic']).tolist()
for i in range(len(topics)):
        topics_dict[topics[i]] = i
df['topic_id'] = [topics_dict[l] for l in df['topic']]
```

However, I am quite sure there is a more elegant and pandaic way to solve this but I couln't find something on Google or SO.
I read about pandas' [get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) but this creates multiple columns for each different value in the original column.

I am thankful for any help or pointer in a direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
In [63]: df['topic'].astype('category').cat.codes
Out[63]:
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    2
4    2
dtype: int8
```

Comment: stumbled upon Categories before but didn't think of simply converting it. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
`pd.factorize`

```
df['topic_id'] = pd.factorize(df.topic)[0]
df

  value  topic  topic_id
0   137   earn         0
1   158   earn         0
2   144   ship         1
3   111  trade         2
4   132  trade         2
```

---

**Option 2**
`np.unique`

```
_, v = np.unique(df.topic, return_inverse=True)
df['topic_id'] = v

df

  value  topic  topic_id
0   137   earn         0
1   158   earn         0
2   144   ship         1
3   111  trade         2
4   132  trade         2
```

---

**Option 3**
`pd.Categorical`

```
df['topic_id'] = pd.Categorical(df.topic).codes
df

  value  topic  topic_id
0   137   earn         0
1   158   earn         0
2   144   ship         1
3   111  trade         2
4   132  trade         2
```

---

**Option 4**
`dfGroupBy.ngroup`

```
df['topic_id'] = df.groupby('topic').ngroup()
df

  value  topic  topic_id
0   137   earn         0
1   158   earn         0
2   144   ship         1
3   111  trade         2
4   132  trade         2
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks. Due to my missing reputation I can't upvote

Comment: @T.Beck I thought you meant to accept mine first, since that's what you did :-) That's why I pointed out, when you accept someone's answer, then accept someone else, the other acceptance is undone. If you meant to tick that answer, that's fine. But if you meant to tick this, do realise that it got undone.

Comment: Just got it now ;)

Comment: `df.groupby('topic').ngroup()` is not working with python3. The error is: `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'ngroup'`

Comment: @rnso Update to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

we can use apply function to create new column based on existing column as shown below.

`topic_list = list(df["topic"].unique())
df['topic_id'] = df.apply(lambda row: topic_list.index(row["topic"]),axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

One can use `for` loops and list comprehension to determine list of codes:

```
ucols = pd.unique(df.topic)
df['topic_id'] = [ j
                for i in range(len(df.topic))
                for j in range(len(ucols))
                if df.topic[i] == ucols[j]  ]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  value  topic  topic_id
0   137   earn         0
1   158   earn         0
2   144   ship         1
3   111  trade         2
4   132  trade         2
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
 df['topic_id'] = pd.Series([0,0,1,2,2], index=df.index)
```

It works good

```
   value  topic
0   137   earn
1   158   earn
2   144   ship
3   111  trade
4   132  trade
  value  topic  topic_id
0   137   earn         0
1   158   earn         0
2   144   ship         1
3   111  trade         2
4   132  trade         2
```

Comment: Good luck with this if you have a million rows.

Comment: We can modify the thing  in [0,0,1,2,2] and it can be random series or any list.